# Catalog Search Refinement issue on admin login

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, admin-panel, logging

I trying for this past few hours, but i can't find out the issue. I installed the "[Catalog Search Refinement](https://extensions.activo.com/catalog-search-refinement.html)" and checked on front end yesterday. Today I'm tried to login on admin panel and i get this error.

```
There has been an error processing your request
Mage registry key "_singleton/catalogsearch2/feed" already exists

Trace:
#0 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/cata...', false)
#2 /var/www/magento/includes/src/__default.php(22033): Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch2/...')
#3 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /var/www/magento/includes/src/__default.php(14361): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#5 /var/www/magento/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#6 /var/www/magento/includes/src/__default.php(14241): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#7 /var/www/magento/includes/src/__default.php(18698): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#8 /var/www/magento/includes/src/__default.php(18228): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /var/www/magento/includes/src/__default.php(21063): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /var/www/magento/index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}

Magento version : 1.9.2.0
PHP version     : 7.0.8
```

Pleas help me to get out from this error.